# Handling empty values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

Hello I am building a query using Microsoft reporting services

[image: 1]

I would like to know how I can only execute the subreport on the ones with a value.

```
WHERE        (QuoteDtl.PartNum = @SRPartNum) AND (QuoteHed.DateQuoted <= N'2020-06-26') AND (QuoteHed.ExpirationDate >= N'2020-07-26') AND (QuoteHed.ShipToNum = @SRShipToNum) AND 
                         (QuoteHed.CustNum = @SRCustNum)
```

`@SRShipToNum` & `@SRCustNum` doesn't always have a value and when it doesn't have a value I am getting this on my report

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ftJ.png

*I also have no idea where the log files are located at*

Comment: you can find the log files on your SSRS hosting server in this folder - > C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: @Harry there isn't no log files for the issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to modify the where clause slightly like this

```
WHERE        
(QuoteDtl.PartNum = @SRPartNum) 
AND (QuoteHed.DateQuoted <= N'2020-06-26') 
AND (QuoteHed.ExpirationDate >= N'2020-07-26') 
AND ((QuoteHed.ShipToNum = @SRShipToNum) or isnull(QuoteHed.ShipToNum ,'')='')
AND ((QuoteHed.CustNum = @SRCustNum or isnull(QuoteHed.CustNum,''='' ) )
```

then in your report front end, make sure you tick this for both your `@SRShipToNum` and `@SRCustNum` parameters :

[image]

Comment: `Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: 'ISNULL' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.` This is what I got.

Comment: Can you please show your full sql query as text in your question ( please edit question with details and not as another comment)